# Batch Renaming on a file share

Tags: windows, powershell, rename, batch-rename

We currently have a CIFS share hosted from a SAN device and are planning to move toward a case management system. The issue I'm having is a lot of the various files in our file share end with a trailing dot (.) and fail to upload.

I've been trying to get a script working that would keep file names the same but batch remove any trailing dots. I've been able to do this with variouse special characters using powershell.

We also have many sub folders that have a dot (.) in the middle of the folder name and would need to leave these alone.

**Example**

Original File name: **20151101 Luis K. Abrishamian M.D..pdf**

New file name: **20151101 Luis K. Abrishamian M.D.pdf**

I used this one to remove all & from file names

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -name | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_ $_.replace("&", "and") }
```

I tried this one but it failed to do what i needed

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -name | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_ $_.replace("*.", "") }
```

Comment: Try escaping. e.g., if every character was renamed to a couple of hex digits, that could work, if filename lengths aren't exceeded.  Although, there may be more efficient ways that involve only escaping what you need to.  Make sure any escape code is suitable unique from any valid text (or that the escape code gets properly escaped).  Not sure offhand about PowerShell (and low on time), so I'll just mention this to help point you (if needed)...  : Escaping is often used in other contexts, like in URLs (maybe programming, e.g. JavaScript's escape() function.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -name |  ForEach-Object { If($_.Substring($_.Length-1) -eq ".") { Move-Item $_ $_.Substring(0,$_.Length-1) } }
```

This will get each item, check if the last character is a `.`, and if it is it'll move it to the same name without the last character.

Comment: No dice. File names remained the same

Comment: @AimdSoldier Any error message?

Comment: No It didn't give me any errors. Used out-file at the end and there was nothing in file

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -name | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_  ([regex]::Replace($_, "\.$" , "")) }
```

Comment: No luck. Trailing dots still there on my test files

Answer (score 0):

Came from an anonymous person at powershell.org

```
# Replace '..' from names (remove one dot)
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path .\my\path | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '\.\.','.'} -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 0):

No one-liners for me.

```
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem 'C:\test' -Recurse) ){
  $newName = $file.DirectoryName + '\' + ( $file.Basename.replace('.', '').replace('&', 'and') ) + $file.Extension
  move-item $file.FullName $newName 
}
```